# Repeated data in edit text in list view

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I am getting repeated data in getview in list view. Can any one give solution.
My code is:

Main activity

```
package com.example.listviewtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

public class MyListAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    MainActivity mainActivity;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private String[] scoresToUpdate=new String[1000] ;
    public MyListAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity=mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 20;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)    
            mainActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.element_in_game, null);

            holder.scoreToUpdate = (EditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt);


            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        final int tmp_position=arg0;
       holder.scoreToUpdate.setText(scoresToUpdate[tmp_position]);
       holder.scoreToUpdate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int before, int count) {
                    scoresToUpdate[tmp_position] = s.toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    class ViewHolder {
        public EditText scoreToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: does it repeat when you scroll or do the repeats show initially?

Comment: ya it do the repeats show initially. And some times text disappears.